# Which zookeeper nodes should not be deleted?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I already googled this info but found nothing decisive. I want to clear my zookeeper, is it alright if I run rmr on all root nodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to delete every node that your system it not using.
Also, you may want to use [ephemeral](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperProgrammers.html#Ephemeral+Nodes) nodes, that get deleted automatically when the connession with zookeeper server is dropped.